To make 'rmdir' and 'find -delete' ignore '.DS_Store' files
On macOS, there is a hidden file .DS_Store in some directories (well, in most of them).
The problem with .DS_Store files is that rmdir and find . -depth 1 -type d -empty -print -delete don't delete such directories.
I suspect there is no straightforward way to handle this, such as nonexistent --ignore_ds_store option of rmdir, so maybe there is a workaround. The default macOS shell is zsh, so maybe the workaround is possible using some of zsh features; so I added the 'zsh' tag to the question.

If there is a .DS_Store or any other hidden file present (files beginning with .), then those directories aren't empty. If you don't want to delete the .DS_Store files, then the command is working exactly as it is designed. I am taking this by your comment to the answer below. Your question can use more clarity on what it is that you want to happen and where there is a malfunction.

@NasirRiley I do understand that technically these folders are not empty. But from the perspective of the user of Finder, I speak just for myself, of course, they are empty. .DS_Store are not visible in Finder even if you enable to show hidden files using Shift-Command-Period; they are only used by Finder and never by the user himself. What I ask here is to make shell understand the Finder user's perspective and to treat such .DS_Store-only folders accordingly.

I understand what you want but neither the shell nor any utility can do anything that it isn't designed to do. If there is any data within a directory whether it is a file, directory, link of any kind, or anything else whether it is hidden or not, the directory isn't empty and that is true regardless of your interpretation. What you are trying to do with that command in particular is not possible unless you are going to edit the source code of find and have it see directories that contain .DS_Store and nothing else to be empty or combine other commands.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78852512

There is no hidden file concept in the macOS basic file system ( HFS or APFS ). This is a concept purely internal to the Finder user view of the reality. The rmdir and find commands cannot deal with a feature of a graphical interface ( the Finder user view of the reality.

zsh is not Finder dependant, thus there isn't any function inside zsh which might deal specifically with Finder way of presenting the filesystem reality. Moreover, this would be an ill conceived function of a Unix shell which is in the standard Unix commands layer.

Note that -delete implies -depth (process leaves between branches they're on).
That's unrelated to FreeBSD's -depth n extension which returns true if the current file being processed is at depth n.
Here you're using -depth n where you should have used -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 (initially from GNU find) to stop find at depth 1.
Here -depth n could be useful though as:
find . -maxdepth 2 '(' \
  -depth 2 -iname .DS_Store -type f -o \
  -depth 1 -type d -empty ')' -delete

Which deletes all .DS_store regular files at depth 2 and empty directory files at depth 1.
Because -delete implies -depth, the .DS_store files in directories are deleted before their parent directory is checked for emptiness.
That has the potentially unwanted side effect also of deleting .DS_store in otherwise not empty directories.
With zsh, you could do:
set -o extendedglob
has_files_other_than_DS_Store() [[ -n $REPLY/^(#i).ds_store(#qNDY1) ]]
rm -rf -- *(/^+has_files_other_than_DS_Store)

But that's potentially dangerous as:

that's racy, if some files are added in between the check and rm, they will be removed.
it doesn't check the type of the .DS_Store file(s), so if it's a directory, it and all its contents will be removed.

In place of rm -rf, you could use a function like
remove_empty_macos_dirs() {
  local dir ret=0
  for dir do
    rm -f -- $dir/.(#i)ds_store(N.) &&
      rmdir -- $dir || ret=$?
  done
  return $ret
}

Which would be less dangerous.

Thanks a lot, Stéphane. There are two side questions. I know there is no technical difference between setopt extendedglob and setopt EXTENDED_GLOB, but I often see the former in snippets to be pasted in command line, and the latter in Zsh configuration files. Is there some convention, logic about this? And the second question. Could you explain the difference (or maybe even better a simple example that explains it) between using -depth 1 and -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1? (find . -depth 1 -type f and find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f, for example, seem to find the same files.)

for option names, case and underscores are ignored. Lowercase no underscore is the simpler to type and what you'll get from completion. Uppercase with underscore makes it more legible and possibly easier to look for in the manual. That's mostly a matter of taste. Except maybe for the standard options such as xtrace, noglob... where using the lowercase no underscore variant helps with portability. That's also why I prefer standard set -o over zsh-specific setopt.

-maxdepth 1 is a global flag that tells find not to descend below depth 1. -depth 1 is a test predicate that returns true if the depth is 1, it doesn't prevent find from descending deeper. You can combine -depth n with -prune to obtain the same effect as -mindepth n -maxdepth n, but not with -delete which implies -depth rendering -prune pointless as it would prune too late.


.DS_Store files can prevent directories from being deleted as they cause the directories to be non-empty.
You can use a combination of shell commands to find and delete these files, and then proceed to remove the now-empty directories.

find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete
find . -type d -empty -delete

Edit :

You can check if the folder is empty or contain only .DS_Store files and then delete it.

#!/bin/zsh

# Function to check and delete empty directories or directories with only .DS_Store files
clean_directories() {
  for dir in $(find . -type d); do
    # Check if directory contains files other than .DS_Store
    if [[ -z $(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -not -name '.DS_Store' -print -quit) ]]; then
      # Delete .DS_Store files in the directory
      find "$dir" -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete
      # Try to remove the directory (will only succeed if it's empty)
      rmdir "$dir" 2>/dev/null
    fi
  done
}

# Run the function to clean directories
clean_directories


".DS_Store files can prevent directories from being deleted as they cause the directories to be non-empty." - Well, yes, I do understand this. "You can use a combination of shell commands to find and delete these files, and then proceed to remove the now-empty directories." - Because I don't want, of course, to delete .DS_Store files from directories that are otherwise nonempty (e.g., if there is a nonempty foobar.txt file there), this cannot be a solution. FWIW, didn't downvote.

Though we can fix this issue by adding some code to check whether there are some other files besides .DS_Store; and if not, then delete such a directory.

@jsx97 edited the solution

Thank you, YassineLbk!
